# Why is the Google Play Store asking for permissions not in my Manifest?

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions

I think this may have to do with the ManifestMerger.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

However the app is asking for:

`Identity`
`Location`
`Photos/Media/Files`

The `manifest-merger-release.txt` says:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:22:5
uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:23:5
android:uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
IMPLIED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:1 reason: com.google.android.gms.maps requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
uses-permission#android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0:21:5
    android:name
        ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0:21:22
uses-permission#android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0:22:5
    android:name
        ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0:22:22
```

But my app is not using google maps etc...

**Update:**

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:034e05997d'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Sometimes if you include libraries in your project, they require permission to function. So these additional permission might come from that, can we see your gradle file please?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` in your build.gradle to the specific part of the play services you need.

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

On this way, the play services doesn't add non-needed permissions

Example:

To use Google Cloud Messaging, just use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0`